# Postgresql : How to join with multiple cross-reference table?

Tags: postgresql, join

I've seen a lot of post on multiple JOIN but it didn't help me in my case.

Consider that I have three tables and two cross-reference tables. That's the difference with the others posts where they had multiple tables but one cross-reference table in the FROM.

Table1 -> cross-ref1 <- table2 -> cross-ref2 <- table3

My version of Postgresql is : 9.0.11, and I'm working with W7 64 bits.

My request is the following stuff :

```
Select [columns] from cross-ref1, cross-ref2

INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.id_table1=cross-ref1.ref_id_table1

INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id=cross-ref1.ref_id_table2

INNER JOIN table2 On table2.id_table2=cross-ref2.ref_id_table2

INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id_table3=cross-ref2.ref_id_table3
```

The error message is : "Table name is specified more than once."

Can you explain me the error ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is the result of the execution of that query on your database?

Comment: Please take a look at the "asking better questions" part of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql/info, then edit your question with `select version()` output, **full, exact error text**, etc and comment here when done. If possible, **provide a test case with sample data on http://sqlfiddle.com/**.

Comment: "*Of course it doesn't work*" is not a valid Postgres error message.

Answer (score 4):

Cross-reference tables need *separate columns* for each side of the reference. An xref table with just one column makes no sense, as it can only refer to rows with the same ID on each side.

A typical setup would be:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
    id integer primary key,
    avalue text not null
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    id integer primary key,
    bvalue text not null
);

CREATE TABLE ab (
     a_id integer references a(id),
     b_id integer references b(id),
     PRIMARY KEY(a_id, b_id)
);
```

Given sample data:

```
INSERT INTO a(id, avalue) VALUES 
(1, 'a1'), (2, 'a2'), (3, 'a3'), (4, 'a4');

INSERT INTO b(id, bvalue) VALUES 
(41, 'b1'), (42, 'b2'), (43, 'b3');

INSERT INTO ab(a_id, b_id) VALUES
(1, 41), (1, 42), (2, 43);
```

You'd find the pairings of `a` and `b` with:

```
SELECT avalue, bvalue
FROM a
INNER JOIN ab ON (a.id = ab.a_id)
INNER JOIN b ON (b.id = ab.b_id);
```

The crucial thing here is that you're joining on `ab.a_id` on the `a` side, and `ab.b_id` on the `b` side. Observe demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3228a/1

This is pretty much "many-to-many table relationships 101", so it might be worth doing some more study of introductory SQL and relational database tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the same table name twice (table2). In this case you need to use aliases like t1, t2a, t2b, ...

```
SELECT
    ...
FROM
   table1 AS t1
   INNER JOIN table2 AS t2a
      ON t2a.id= ...
   INNER JOIN table2 AS t2b
      ON t2b.id= ...
   INNER JOIN table3 AS t3
      ON t3.id= ...
   ...
```

Now you can join whatever you want, how many times you want etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to explain what result you want to have. For example the following SQL is valid from syntax point of view, not sure about business point of view:

```
-- this will create sample data with 5 tables
with 
crossref1(ref_id) as (VALUES (1),(2),(3)),
crossref2 (ref_id) as (VALUES (2),(3),(4)),
table1 (ref_id) as (VALUES (3),(4),(5)),
table2 (ref_id) as (VALUES (1),(2),(3)),
table3 (ref_id) as (VALUES (1),(2),(3))


-- valid SQL based on your example
select * from 
crossref1  
cross join crossref2
join table1 on table1.ref_id=crossref1.ref_id
join table2 as t2_1 on t2_1.ref_id=crossref1.ref_id
join table2 as t2_2 on t2_2.ref_id=crossref2.ref_id
join table3 on table3.ref_id=crossref2.ref_id
```

With your SQL there are two problems:

- You have two references to table2, you have to add alias
- You have to use `cross join` syntax instead of `,`

If you would like to understand how `with` works (how I created sample data), PostgreSQL has excellent [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) on this.

Comment: Quick tip: If you want to use a CTE for sample data in Pg, you can use `WITH blah(col1, col2) AS (VALUES(1,2),(3,4,),(5,6))` instead. Much more concise and IMO clearer. If you're going to use a CTE rather than `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` for sample data, it's worth explaining what's going on, as most new users will never have even seen `WITH` - and if they're asking questions about `INNER JOIN` they're a new user.